# Perform async operation on list in dart

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

I have a problem in which I have to map some elements of a list (here `types`) into some other elements of the same type but with an async operation.

```dart
Future<String> getData() async {
  return await "hi";
}

void main() {
  List<String> types = ["", "", ""];
  List<String> otherTypes = types.map((e) async {
    return await getData();
  }).toList();
}
```

But the code will not compile with the following error.

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
main.dart:9:6:
Error: A value of type 'List<Future<String>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  }).toList();
     ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

PS: I tried above code already on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List<Future> cannot be converted to Future<List> without using another for loop and alternatively you can create a list and use conventional for each loop. example is follows

```
Future<String> getData() async {
  return await "hi";
}

void main() async{
  List<String> types = ["", "", ""];
  List<String> otherTypes = List();
  for(var s in types)
     otherTypes.add(await getData());
}
```

P.S. future value can be accessed only with async function, or else you have to use (future value).then() call back.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, a `List<Future<T>>` can be converted to a `Future<List<T>>` with [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html).

Comment: Or `List<String> otherTypes = [for (var v in types) await getData()];`. As long as the surrounding function is async, you can await anywhere.